# How to add page length in datatables when using ajax implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add pageLength to my datatables with ajax implementation but when I try to see the results, it returns a lot on the table instead of slicing the data for each page. Please see my code below.

**JS**

```
$('table.dataTableAjax').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "paging": true,
  "pageLength": 50,
  "ajax": "..."
});
```

I also tried the code below but still not working fine.

```
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
```

**Example Data From Server Side**

```
{
    "data":[
        { "name": "Bob" },
        { "name": "Billy" }
    ]
}
```

In my server side, I'm throwing about 500+ data rows.

So the current result is it returns all the 500+ table rows instead of 50 table rows each page.

Comment: Is your ajax data dynamic or is it some static file that will never change?

Comment: @bassxzero it is dynamic; directly from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you configured the `serverSide` property as "true" in the datatable configuration. If you enable it, the server should be responsible for limiting the number of rows that need to be sent. You can try disabling the `serverSide` option and see.

```
$('table.dataTableAjax').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": false,
  "paging": true,
  "pageLength": 50,
  "ajax": "..."
});
```

Comment: Okay it works, but what if I want to use the `serverSide`? Is there any performance difference? I'm doing this to load the table faster

Comment: Yes, there definitely will be a performance difference because you load only a set of data from the server, and also the page will not be heavy. Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Okay, can you give me an example of data returned from the server in case I want to use `serverSide` option?

Comment: It is the same as the data you returned earlier but with a fewer number of rows. Let's say you need to get 50 rows, then the server only returns 50 rows to the front-end instead of sending all the 500 rows

Comment: https://dev.to/stephencweiss/server-side-pagination-with-limit-offset-296e

Comment: Okay so basically, I just have to handle all sorting, search, paging in server side part?

Comment: Yes, You need to do that

Comment: Okay, got it :)

Answer (score 1):

`"serverSide": true,`
Read the manual on Server-side processing https://datatables.net/manual/server-side
Specifically the stuff about `length` and `start`

All of the processing, row limiting, filtering, paging, etc. is implemented in your server side script.

Here is a sample php script for server side datatables processing, but I'm not sure what version you are using. (This is the legacy datatables version) https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Some example of what you need to implement on the back end is something like this.

```
<?php 

// Build your query up here
$query = "select * from some_table where blah ":

// For paging
// If the request supplied a place to start
if ( isset( $request['start'] ) && $request['length'] != '-1' ) {
    // Add a limit section to your query
    $query = $query . "LIMIT $request['start'],$request['length'] ";

}
```